# timer which will stop at specific time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, timer

I want to do a timer which will countdown starting from 8AM EST and finish at 6PM EST. Once the timer is at 00:00:00, I want to hide the control from the website, and then display again the next day at the same time.
Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Timers in JavaScript run in millisecond increments, so you need to figure out the number of milliseconds to the countdown time.

Formatting times and dates in JavaScript are a bit of a pain, luckily there are a few utilities like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) that can help.

You'll need a timer that runs in 1000ms intervals (1 second) that will tick down your displayed date. You'll also need to compare the current date/time to the times you want to hide/show your counter. Date.js can help with this too.